# How to get all my applications' visit times running in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

**Is this a BUG REPORT or FEATURE REQUEST?**:

feature

**What happened**:

How to get all my applications' visit times running in kubernetes? something like visitor counter for website. Any suggestions?

**What you expected to happen**:

Get the total count. via kube-proxy?

**How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible)**:

Nothing

**Anything else we need to know?**:

**Environment**:

- Kubernetes version (use `kubectl version`):
- Cloud provider or hardware configuration**:

kubernetes:  v1.6.3 
1 master + 3 node + dashboard + ingress +...
docker 1.12.6
etcd3
flannel

- OS (e.g. from /etc/os-release):
  Linux centos7.3
- Kernel (e.g. `uname -a`):
- Install tools:
- Others:

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to check the monitoring and metrics tools available, such as Prometheus: https://coreos.com/blog/monitoring-kubernetes-with-prometheus.html. Here you can find an example of http request queries, which should work for your case: https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/examples/